# add div content before autotable

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Iam using theese plugins
**
1) jspdf.plugin.autotable.js 
2) jspdf.debug.js **

Iam using the following code

```
var pdf = new jsPDF("p", "pt");
pdf.fromHTML($("#otherdivcontent").get(0), 70, 300, {
width: 500
});
var res = pdf.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("table2"));

pdf.autoTable(res.columns, res.data);

pdf.autoPrint();

pdf.save("Report.pdf");
```

script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
```

this is the generated pdf
[image: generated pdf]

I want to combine the two contents into a single pdf...and i want the div content before the table....please help me to adjust the alignments. I want the table in a second page...
How can i solve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution,

```
pdf.fromHTML($("#test1").get(0), 30,100, {
            'width': margins.width
            },
            margins);
 pdf.autoTable(data.columns, data.rows, 
        {margin: {top: 80,bottom:50},
        startY:h+20,
        tableWidth: 500,
        styles: {
        overflow: 'linebreak',
        columnWidth: 'wrap',
        // rowHeight:'wra',
        lineWidth: 1
        }});
```

"h" is the height of the div #test1.

Comment: iam using "jspdf.min.js" instead of "jspdf.debug.js"